# Serialize only few fields and return rest django

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is serializer caller from views.py django

```
serialized_data = IoSerializer(data=request.data)
serialized_data.is_valid(True)
```

My serializer file

```
from rest_framework import serializers

#All validations here
class BudgetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end_date = serializers.DateField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
     
class IoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
        name  =  serializers.CharField()
        state =  serializers.CharField()
        budget_intervals = BudgetSerializer(many=True)
```

My json which i am sending to serializer.py.Note I am sending json i have not used model.

```
{    "name": "V_test",
     "state": "inactive",
     "currency": "USD",
    "budget_intervals": [
    {
        "start_date": "2020-12-16 00:00:00",
        "end_date": "2020-12-18 23:59:59",
        "lifetime_budget": 1000
    }
],
   "budget_type": "revenue",
    "POLITICAL_CONTENT" : {
    "government_level":3,
    "is_accuracy_acknowledged":"true" 
} 
}
```

question : serialized_data.data in my views only outputs fields of json which are mentioned in serializer.py file i.e not currency,lifetime_budget etc.

What i want is to validate only few fields.But when printing serialize_data.data i am getting only those json fields which are in serializer.py

Comment: I don't understand what you want, please show exactly what you need for the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-rest-framework` serializer serializes only the fields you explicitly mention. It does not do anything with unmentioned fields nor serialize them. Since you do not want any kind of validation on fields e.g.- `currency, lifetime_budget` you can mention them in your serializer class with `read_only = True`. But, that brings us to another problem i.e. `rest_framework` serializers return values for read_only fields only when a python object instance is supplied to them or a python object instance is returned from `serializer.save()` method. Keeping in mind that you do not want to override the `save` method I'm going to answer in the approach of supplying an object.

`serializers.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

#All validations here
class BudgetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    end_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    lifetime_budget = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True) # new read only field
    # you can add more read only fields here

class IoSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name  =  serializers.CharField()
    state =  serializers.CharField()
    budget_intervals = BudgetSerializer(many=True)
    currency = serializers.CharField(read_only=True) # new read only field for currency
    # more read only fields
```

I have changed the `start_date` and `end_date` to `DateTimeField` since your data is supplying `datetime`.

In your `view`

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

# inside view
data = json.dumps(request.data) # since request is an OrderedDict not json
io_object = json.loads(data, object_hook=lamdba x: namedtuple('io_object', x.keys())(*x.values()))
serializer = IoSerializer(data=request.data, instance=io_object)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # do your validation
print(serializer.data) # will return with your desired read only data
```